# Create 2 https virtual hosts same IP

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, ssl

I have domain "domain1.com" which uses ip "1.1.1.1" and is configured:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain1.com
.......
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain1.com
.......
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to add new domain name which uses same IP, "domain2.com"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain2.com
.......
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain2.com
.......
</VirtualHost>
```

But when i restart apache it says:

```
[warn] VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443 overlaps with VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
```

And when i tried to open any of them, 1st domain certificate showed as if there is no SSL, 2nd domain was okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `NameVirtualHost` while doing virtual hosting

```
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

if you want to receive requests on all interfaces, you can use an argument of `*:443`

you can take help from [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html#using).

add like:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443

NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain1.com
.......
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain1.com
.......
</VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain2.com
.......
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain2.com
.......
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What if i have 2 separated virtual hosts files (`domain1.conf`, `domain2.conf`) under sites-available, do i need to add that line `NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443` to both files?

Comment: i have not tested but i think it is not required . you can keep it any one file . it simple means is you ip listen on port 443 and 80.  conceptually is is not needed .

Comment: please test this and share with me also . i am also interested to see what will happen.

Comment: I tested it, it considered one of them as unused `[warn] NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443 has no VirtualHosts`, one of them is enough